# Spring prevent user from accessing url through browser and ajax

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am having a trouble with Springs Security Configuration. I am sharing my code below.

My problem is I want `/user*` url and `/admin*` url should be accessed only when the user is logged in to my application, my application has major ajax calls so I want no user have access to `/user*` URL without logging in. But when I tried to type the URL in web browser I was not even redirected to login page, instead I am getting on the page which is typed in the URL.

So can anyone please help me with this issue.

spring-security.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
     xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/user/home"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select USERNAME, PASSWORD from USER where USERNAME = ?"
            authorities-by-username-query="ROLE_USER"
        />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><web-app 
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Admin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Admin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>User</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>User</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
              org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/User-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/Spring-Datasource.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
              org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
          <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value/>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

ControllerServlet.java

```
    @Controller
    public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUserLoginPage(){
        return "user/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showErrorLoginPage(ModelMap modelMap){
        modelMap.addAttribute("message", "Invalid Login Credentials");
        return "user/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUserHomePage(ModelMap modelMap, Principal principal){
       //String name = principal.getName();
       //modelMap.addAttribute("name", name);
       return "user/home";  
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLogoutPage(ModelMap modelMap){
       return "user/index";
    }
    }
```

DB Design / Code :

```
    create table USER(ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, USERNAME varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE, PASSWORD varchar(20) NOT NULL, FIRSTNAME varchar(25) NOT NULL, LASTNAME varchar(25) NOT NULL, UPDATED_ON varchar(25) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

Login Form Code :

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST"
                action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" id="loginForm">
                <div class="span4"></div>
                <div class="span5" style="background-color: #FBFBFC; border: solid 1px #CCC;padding: 30px 5px 30px 5px;">
                <div class="span1"></div>
                <fieldset>                      
                    <legend>Login Here</legend>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" name="j_username" id="username"
                                placeholder="Username"
                                title="Please enter your username" data-placement="right" />
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <span id="errorSpan"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="j_password" id="password"
                                placeholder="Password" title="Please enter your password"
                                data-placement="right" />
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <span id="errorSpan"></span>
                    </div>


                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label>&nbsp;</label>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign In" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="span1"></div>
                </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="span3"></div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

First, you have to correct the address patterns: like `user/**`

Second, if you have restful calls to your secured resources, this likely happenes.
Check the firebug. You'll see a `302 redirect` as a response to your request. In this case, you better not use redirecting, but giving a `403 access denied` response and handle it manually within your ajax framework.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your response, can you please help me with one more case that why I am getting the same login page with error in login, even if my putting the correct login credentials.

Comment: Have you checked your `database.USER` table? Is your password correct? Is it encrypted? Failure in login is caused by one of these scenarios.

Comment: No sir, my password is not encrypted. Is it necessary to be encrypted. And I am entering the correct password and username.

Comment: It is not necessary to have your passwords encrypted, but it is recommended. Check your query separately. Does it load correctly?

Comment: I was not able to login, because I was not having an ENABLED field in my USER Table and I am also not creating the ROLES Table. But I don't understand why enabled field is needed and why we need to create a seprate Role table as well in Springs Security.

Comment: Well, `IS_ACTIVE` is needed for the type of authentication you are using. _You can have your own `user details service` and implement this authentication the way you like_. `ROLE` is also necessary, since it should be clear to your authentication manager, what the user's role is.

Comment: Sir, one more query ? How will spring security works with Google BigTable since we don't have SQL Queries in BigTable.

Comment: I am not familiar with GoogleBigTable; however, you can always customize the way Spring authenticates (like avoiding queries), by having your own `userDetailsService`.

Comment: Sir, can you please share a link here where custom authentication is done using Springs Security at Controller level or at Filter level.

Comment: I can give you an example if you want. But I believe that's another question.

Comment: Yes Sir, you are right, can you please send me the link to my email :
ankur_150889@yahoo.com

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is wrong

```
pattern="/user/**"
```

should be right.
To understand the stars in pattern a bit better:

- `xx/**` means the complete tree structure beneath `xx` is
  secured.
- `xx/*` means only the data in `xx` is secured.
- `xx/*.rar` in this case `*` is a wildcard for files so all .rar files
  are secured.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are absolutely right, this is working fine, but having problem that it is not allowing me to access the the page even I am putting the correct username and password.

Comment: I do not know about ajax stuff cos I always used ZK-Framework for ajax login and I do not know if it is the same in pure Spring. For now I do not see the name/pw problem. Post code for login page and db-connection would be the best.

Answer (score 1):

You should also specify a query for **authorities-by-username-query** as you did for 
**users-by-username-query**

```
<jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
     users-by-username-query="select USERNAME, PASSWORD from USER where USERNAME = ?"
     authorities-by-username-query="ROLE_USER"
/>
```

For example

```
authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, ur.authority from user u, user_roles ur 
              where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username =?"
```

Also consider adding a [password-encoder](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-password-encoder) in your configuration, so that you don't have plain text passwords in your database

Comment: Sir, but I don't have any roles tables in my DB yet. Is it really necessary to have Role in DB yet.